# How do I avoid $$ -> $ replacement in stored procedure body after compiling it with ant sql task?

Tags: ant

After running ant sql task my sql procedure turns from:

```
create or replace procedure test
is
begin
  dbms_output.put_line($$plsql_line, 'demo');
end;
```

into

```
create or replace procedure test
is
begin
  dbms_output.put_line($plsql_line, 'demo');
end;
```

Ant task is:

```
<target name="test">
    <record name="test-log" />

    <sql userid="dev"
         password="dev"
         url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.1:1521:DEMODB"
         keepformat="yes"
         driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
         delimiter="/"
         encoding="utf8"
         escapeprocessing="false"
         delimitertype="normal">
        <fileset dir=".">
            <include name="test.sql"/>
        </fileset>
    </sql>
</target>
```

How to force Ant not to replace '$$' with '$' ?

Answer (score 0):

See [ant manual properties / property expansion](http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html) :

> In order to maintain backward compatibility with older Ant releases, a
>   single '$' character encountered apart from a property-like construct
>   (including a matched pair of french braces) will be interpreted
>   literally; that is, as '$'. The "correct" way to specify this literal
>   character, however, is by using the escaping mechanism
>   unconditionally, so that "$$" is obtained by specifying "$$$$". Mixing
>   the two approaches yields unpredictable results, as "$$$" results in
>   "$$".

Means you need to use `$$$$...` , see :

```
<project>

<echo>
  1.
  create or replace procedure test
  is
  begin
    dbms_output.put_line($$plsql_line, 'demo');
  end;
</echo>


<echo>
  2.
  create or replace procedure test
  is
  begin
    dbms_output.put_line($$$$plsql_line, 'demo');
  end;
</echo>

</project>
```

output :

```
[echo]   1.
[echo]   create or replace procedure test
[echo]   is
[echo]   begin
[echo]     dbms_output.put_line($plsql_line, 'demo');
[echo]   end;
[echo]   2.
[echo]   create or replace procedure test
[echo]   is
[echo]   begin
[echo]     dbms_output.put_line($$plsql_line, 'demo');
[echo]   end;
```

**-- EDIT after comment --**

Copy your original sql files, then edit the copied files with [replace task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html) and run sqltask with edited files :

```
<!-- copy ... -->
<replace dir="..." value="$$$$$$$$" token="$$$$">
 <include name="**/*.sql"/>
</replace>
<!-- sql ... -->
```

Comment: The problem is I have separate .sql files, and I would like not to alter .sql content, because they would be unusable without ant.